# How to customize XYLineChart with JFreeChart

Tags: java, charts, jfreechart

I have an XYLineChart generated from an XYSeriesCollection.

The chart looks like that:

[image: standard chart]

I would like to customize it in order to put into evidence the domain axis entry of the dataset, using some dots (or circles, or squares).  It should look like:

[image]

Has JFreeChart some feature do achieve that result? 
Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep: see the image in http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/renderer/category/LineAndShapeRenderer.html, and unless I'm wrong you can do it using [this](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/renderer/xy/XYLineAndShapeRenderer.html).

Comment: :I need just an advice: setShapeVisible method is now deprecated (http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/renderer/category/LineAndShapeRenderer.html#setShapesVisible%28java.lang.Boolean%29). How can I replace it? with which method of which class?

Comment: I think you want `setSeriesShapesVisible`: http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/renderer/category/LineAndShapeRenderer.html#setSeriesShapesVisible%28int,%20java.lang.Boolean%29.

Answer (score 0):

Just use this constructor for the renderer:

```
LineAndShapeRenderer(boolean lines, boolean shapes)
```

and set both values to true.